# Changing Android Camera IDs with USB Device?

Tags: java, android, uvc

I have developed an app that displays a `UVC` camera connected via USB to the device using a combination of `libusb` and `libuvc` in a `JNI` manner.

What I want to do is figure out a way of running a service on boot-up that will assign this USB camera the rear-facing camera's ID so that other applications can use it by simply requesting to use the back camera which would really be the USB camera since it has the rear facing camera's ID.

Would something like this be possible? Also, how would I go about reassigning Camera IDs? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I will be very unhappy if this is possible, outside of rooted device or perhaps a system app. Ordinary Android SDK apps should not be able to shuffle around camera ID values, let alone cause other data sources to masquerade as the rear-facing camera.

Comment: If I have to root, that is fine. I just don't know how or which way to approach this case whether I have to root or not. It seems as though Android SDK will not allow me to change Camera IDs. Furthermore, the attached device is not of Camera type so I am not sure if there is a straight forward approach to this. Again, any help is appreciated though.

Comment: @QuonTechaholic, did you ever figure whether this is possible, and/or how to do it?